# iText pdfcopy close off by one error

Tags: java, pdf, itext, off-by-one

I see this error a lot in an application with a lot of traffic when dealing with a PDF merge request.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: The page 3 was requested but the document
>   has only 2 pages.   at
>   com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter.close(PdfWriter.java:1169)   at
>   com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfCopy.close(PdfCopy.java:485)   at ...

The error is in the `PdfCopy` class, `addPage` method:

```
public void addPage(PdfImportedPage iPage) throws IOException, BadPdfFormatException

pageRef = getCurrentPage(); // increase pageReferences.size()
```

But later on an `IOException` occurs (`ClientAbortException`), but the last line `++currentPageNumber;` didn't get a chance to execute.

How do I prevent this from happening? Can I add a finally block in the last line?

Comment: Do you know what causes the `IOException`?

Comment: You're using a version of iText that is no longer supported (it's 7 years old!!!). Please upgrade and post a new question if the problem persists.

Comment: Furthermore you mention a `ClientAbortException` - as far as I know iText does not throw (or regularly cause) such an exception. Thus, you seem to have a third library interfering in your iText using code.

Comment: It is org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException. which extends java.io.IOExceptio.